# Using java to pull data from object Server?

Tags: java, jdbc

> An object server is the component of an OnDemand system that holds the
>   reports that are accessed by your users. An object server belongs to
>   an OnDemand instance. An instance is a logical server environment
>   consisting of a library server, one or more object servers, a
>   database, and cache storage. [link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cmod/v8r4m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.ondemand.mp.doc/arsa0341.htm)

Is it possible to pull data from IBM object server using JDBC?How to pull data from object server using Java JDBC? Actually I want to read data from alert.status table of Object Server. More info about  [Object server table](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v8r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.netcool_OMNIbus.doc_7.2.0/common/reference/omn_ref_tab_alertsstatus.html)

Comment: Looks like it: http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/i/software/toolbox/faqjdbc.html

Comment: @DarkStar1 this seems more about DB2 ?? Is DB2 == object Server??

Comment: I haven't been in the dbase dev circle for long but my understanding is that your ORM is a framework layer in your application that connects with the database Look at Hibernate for example.

Comment: @Dark Star1 So is it same as connecting to general database?

Comment: Yeah except you let the ORM do all the work of connecting and managing your object persistence.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, you want to access archived documents from an IBM OnDemand archiving system. The system consists of archived documents stored by the Object Server and associated index information stored by the Library Server.

While the Library Server uses a SQL database, the Object Server doesn't. So you cannot access it with JDBC.

However, there is a Java API called ODWEK (OnDemand Web Enablement Kit). You can find the [Red Book](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247646.pdf) on the net. And if you google for ODWEK, you can find more informatin about it.

Comment: Do we access tables in object server using ODWEK The first chaper of documentations shows some file system ?

Comment: The Object Server has no tables. It stores just the documents. All the additional structured information is stored by the Library Server. But it should matter to you because ODWEK provides access to both parts of the overall system.

Comment: Actually I wanted to access alert.status table from object server and copy it's content to my local database. Could you suggest me some approch??

Comment: I've never come across a table called alert.status. Are you sure this is about the OnDemand archiving system?

Comment: this is about I have edited question too  : http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v8r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.netcool_OMNIbus.doc_7.2.0/common/reference/omn_ref_tab_alertsstatus.html

Comment: Then it's not about OnDemand but about Tivoli. The initial quote in your question is thus misleading and probably wrong. You better start a new question with the correct information.